# CXF and multiple servlet mappings

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, cxf, jax-rs

Currently we have a Java webapp with a Spring MVC DispatcherServlet and two CXFServlets. The DispatcherServlet is the default servlet (mapping `/`), one CXFServlet maps to `/api/*`, the other to `/services/*`.

What is bugging me, is that it seems impossible to have 1 CXFServlet that hosts 2 services, one on `/api/v0` and one on `/services/myService`, without mapping `/*` to the CXFServlet. If this were possible, it would save the initialisation time, config hassle and memory requirements of another servlet instance.

So basically, my question is if anyone knows of a way to host 2 CXF services on 2 URLs in 1 CXFServlet, without a common base/root URL, preferably using the Spring namespaces config, without mapping `/*` to the CXFServlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `invoke` method of the [CXF ServletController](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/rt/transports/http/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/transport/servlet/ServletController.java) first calls `HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo`, which returns the part of the requested URL *without* the servlet's `url-pattern`. The result of this call is then used to match any defined service through a call to `DestinationRegistry#getDestinationForPath`. It is therefore currently impossible to have CXF match services using a path with the servlet part included — CXF never calls `HttpServletRequest#getServletPath` which would be needed for this.

Note that the `base-address` value that can be set in the servlet's initialisation parameters (`<init-param>`) will only affect any URLs that CXF *displays*, because the `ServletController#getBaseURL` method that uses this value is not used during service invocation.